# Measure CPU/RAM Usage while querying in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, cpu-usage

I have a database set up on MongoDB and I want to calculate the CPU and RAM usage for various queries.

I'm trying to use the psutil library to do this. Here is one such example :

```
process = psutil.Process(44083) # Got the pid of mongod running by ps aux | grep mongod

mem_usage = process.memory_info()[0]
cpu_usage = process.cpu_percent()
print mem_usage, cpu_usage

cursor = db.production.find({'key':value})

mem_usage = process.memory_info()[0]
cpu_usage = process.cpu_percent()
print mem_usage, cpu_usage
```

Is this the correct way to get the desired metrics?

Comment: I think you should try using a Mongo monitoring tool for this. You will be able to see live stats while queries are running.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use one of free tools like Datadog, ServerDensity, NewRelic. They have free plans and are able to gather mongo statistics as well.

But why do you need to measure CPU and memory usage when you dont have control over that?

I would rather focus on building proper schema and indexes and then measure their usage, cpu and ram are only indicators that `somethings going on`. Mongo statistics on the other hand can tell you `what` is going on.

Here are some useful links from Mongo documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/

Comment: I'll take a look at the free tools. I was comparing the cpu and ram usage of Mongo with Oracle, that's why.

Comment: I dont think it is comparable. My try to do this would be benchmarking, data size, index size and query response time. Just take a look at comparisons between different databases, they all compare indicators like inerts per second, not the CPU used.